# How do you change the linespread for a just a certain part of the paper

Tags: formatting, line-spacing

I am trying to change the distance between lines for only a particular section of my paper. I am using `\linespread{2}` at the top of my paper and it seems that any other `\linespread` I use will be overridden by it. How do I change the `\linespread` for just a section of my paper?

Comment: Use the `setspace` package and then you have access to `\singlespacing` and `\doublespacing` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setspace` package to do this.

I often find spacing a little unsatisfying when moving between double and single spacing, so I introduce a little correction. (There's probably a better way of doing this.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\spacecorrection}{%
  \vspace*{-\dp\strutbox}%
  \vspace*{\lineskip}}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\spacecorrection
\singlespacing
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\doublespacing
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\selectfont` to apply changes to `\linespread`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\linespread{1.0}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\linespread{2.5}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.

\end{document}
```

[image: preview]